# hide or encrypt form params in url rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, pagination, sunspot

I have this form:

```
<%= form_tag posts_path, :method => :get, :class => "search_nav" do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], :class => "input-long search-query", :placeholder => "#{t('.search_nav')}"  %>
     <%= hidden_field_tag('ip', "#{request.ip}") %>
     <%= hidden_field_tag('city', "#{request.location.city}") %>
     <%= hidden_field_tag('country', "#{request.location.country}") %>
     <%= content_tag(:div, "",:class => "icon-search") %>
<% end %>
```

I get a url something like:

```
http://localhost:3000/en/posts?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=check+params&ip=127.0.0.1&city=&country=Reserved
```

My question is:

**Can I hide or encrypt the url params `ip, city and country`?**

I can not use `POST` because I have paginate results:

```
<a rel="2" href="/en/posts?city=&country=Reserved&ip=127.0.0.1&page=2&search=check+params&utf8=%E2%9C%93">2</a> 
<a rel="3" href="/en/posts?city=&country=Reserved&ip=127.0.0.1&page=3&search=check+params&utf8=%E2%9C%93">3/a>
```

Comment: Why do you need to add those hidden fields into the form? They're all part of the request object so you might as well access them directly from your controller action that handles the form submission.

Comment: It is correct your response. I can get ip, city and country on my controller. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encrypting URL parameters is pretty pointless. Why don't you want the user to see these values? Sure you COULD encrypt them before adding them to the form, but is that really necessary?

Furthermore, and perhaps more importantly, if these values are based on the request, then there is a good chance you don't need to submit them in the first place. `#{request.xxx}` is going to be the same on the result page as is on the form page. Is there any good reason to pass these along? By submitting these as GET parameters, you're actually sending redundant information to the server. Ruby/Rails is already going to calculate these values based off of the IP address automatically when the next page is loaded.

The problem here isn't with the form, but rather with the logic you've applied to designing it.  I think you may have over-analysed your situation, and need to take a step back and re-think the problem.

Comment: Thank you but it's correct the @Teoulas comment I don't need get ip, country and city in my form. I can get this params in my controller. Thank you!